# Adding a Limit Option to Ecto's Repo.preload in Elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a function in Elixir using Ecto that preloads associations for a given entity. The current implementation looks like this:

```
@spec get(integer() | String.t(), list()) :: t() | nil
def get(id, preloads \\ []) do
  Shop
  |> Repo.get(id)
  |> Repo.preload(preloads)
end
```

i use it like this:

```
      Shop.get(id, [
        :coustomers,
        :products
      ])
```

and is it possible do make it like this ?:

```
  Shop.get(id, [
    :coustomers,
    {:limit,:products,3}
  ])
```

Comment: I am imagining how to do this using normal SQL for, say, Postgres. When we do a `join`, that will by default return a row for each found association. If you have 20 products, there will be 20 rows. Therefore it seems most efficient to be able to somehow `where product.some_index < 3`. I am just not sure what `some_index` would be. It could be an actual column in the products table or it could be the result of a (subquery)[https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/aggregates-and-subqueries.html#subqueries].

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to limit the number of preloaded records, but it takes more than a one liner and is maybe not as flexible as you would hope or expect:

```
products_query = from p in Product, limit: 3, order_by: p.inserted_at

Shop
|> Repo.get(id)
|> Repo.preload([products: products_query])
```

Maybe you can create a function that takes a Module and a number (for the limit) and returns something identical to the `products_query` above, like:

```
def preload_query(module, limit) do
  from a in module, limit: ^limit
end
```

And use this as an argument for `Shop.get/2`:

```
Shop.get(id, [:customers, products: preload_query(Product, 3)])
```

Comment: The docs say "operations like limit and offset in the preload query will affect the whole result set and not each association". https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3

Comment: Yes, lot of gotchas when using preloads. For this (simple) case, I don't think it matters though?

Comment: I think it does matter. Since your subquery has no `where` on the shop_id, you will be listing the 3 most recently inserted products, belonging to any shop.

Comment: Ah, but this is `Repo.preload`, not `Query.preload`. :) It will only return records associated with the given shop, so that's fine. And `Repo.preload` also runs a separate query for the preloaded associations and since we only want put a simple limit on them that should be fine too. Just confirmed it with some tests just to be sure. 
For brevity my answer was using just `preload` instead of `Repo.preload`, updated.

Comment: You are right. My mind just redacted the `Repo.` part of your answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```elixir
defmodule Shops do
  def get_shop(nil), do: nil

  def get_shop(shop_id) do
    limited_products =
      Product
      |> where(shop_id: ^shop_id)
      |> limit(3)

    Shop
    |> from(as: :shop)
    |> join(:inner, [shop: shop], product in subquery(limited_products), on: true, as: :products)
    |> select([shop: shop, products: products], %{shop | products: products})
    |> Repo.one()
  end
end
```

I have not tested this. It is just for illumination.